# download multiply images to pc by python

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, wget

I Have a dataframe

[image]

per each ID - id of image on google drive (not my but shared with me). Want to download this images and save them.

```
for i in range(profile_links_df.shape[0]):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id="
    url = URL + profile_links_df['id_pic'].iloc[i]
    name = 'id_pic'+str(i)+'.png'
    wget.download(url, name)
```

Problems :

Try
wget.download
urllib.request.urlretrieve

loop stops at 30-50 iteration with 403 Forbidden (with no depends from link)

Try shutil.copyfileobj
After 10-20 iterations downloading files with 1kb size

How i can correclty download data?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Does it work? Have you downloaded correctly at least one of images? If there is exception, can you show text of exception?

Comment: Code is correct. I have some saved pics. Failed after big count of downloads

Comment: Does retrying these failed files help anyhow? Or after several retries all bad files give same error again? Also have you tried re-downloading previous successful images? Maybe after first error all previous successful images are also un-downloadable with this error? It could be the case that after many downloads Google bans queries because of some protection. Against denial of service attacks.

Comment: I was try to do timeout for 5 sec  between downloads but problem is actual

Comment: If you wait for some time (like 1 hour) does problem still remain? Also when there are errors have you tried downloading again previous successfully downloaded files? Do they have problems too or they are downloadable?

Comment: problem is fixed after reload python client or after maybe 1-2 hours. No problems with redownoading files. They are creating like copies

Comment: So it is definitely some ban from Google side. Probably protection against unwanted frequent queries or DOSS attack. It can't be fixed anyhow. Even if you use different proxies then probably Google ban comes from initial account that shared files, but you can check using proxies.